# Git does not show remote messages (output of origin's hook)

Tags: git, hook, message

My pre-receive hook at remote origin is:

```
#!/bin/sh  
echo "****************************"
```

I used to see the echo at client console like `remote: ***************************`, but now it does not show the remote message any more. Not sure which change caused it.

What should I do to see the remote message?

Comment: Try `echo "****************************************" >&2`

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: "Not sure which change caused it." What changes have occurred on the server?

Comment: It has passed a lot of days, so not sure of the changes.  One signicant change is I installed gitweb, but I'm not sure if the issue occured after gitweb installed.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically saying your `pre-receive` script is returning a non-zero status. git [pre-receive documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) states that any non-zero status will not accept the new commits.

Comment: The problem is with remote echo. Not to do with status. The real logic is to reject pushes that are not rebased to "latest".

Comment: @LeonZeng so the push is working, just the output that is missing?

Comment: Yes, output missing in the client.